# ¿Porqué me da este error: Warning: Password input may be echoed.?

Tags: python, contraseña

Estoy intentando introducir un input oculto con la librería getpass, pero da este error: 'Warning: Password input may be echoed'. Me podrías decir que código introducir para que el int introducido sea oculto y aparezcan *** cuando se escribe.

```
print(f'Has eligido el juego {dificultades[respuesta_dificultad - 1]} introduce un número entre 1 y 1000 para que el jugador 2 lo adivine.')
intentos = 0
max_intentos = intentos_dificultad[respuesta_dificultad -1]

**adivinar = getpass.getpass('Introduce el número: ')**
```

Muchas gracias!

He intentado con esta librería pero no me deja.

Comment: La propia documentación  de `getpass` indica que se solicita una contraseña pero sin hacer *eco*, es decir que te mostrará el input, podrás ingresar datos pero no verás absolutamente nada, ni siquiera una serie de  `*`

Comment: Hola Christian, el problema que tengo es que si que veo el número que introduzco y me aparece este warning

Comment: Esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41160698) te podría ayudar

Comment: ejecuta el programa en una terminal y no dentro de un IDE

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar:

```
from pwinput import pwinput
```

y luego:

```
passw = pwinput('PASSWORD?: ', '*')
#passw = getpass.getpass("Introduce el password")
```

usa

```
pip install pwinput
```